# Rails Paperclip undefined method `validates_attachment'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment

I'm getting the error message from some validation code I have in my model. My system is using paperclip to attach many files to a help article, and I know I have paperclip installed because I'm able to upload files just not validate them.

Here's my model:

```
class HelpAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :help

  has_attached_file :attachment, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment :attachment, :content_type => [ 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', "application/pdf", 
                                    'video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime', 'video/x-ms-asf', 'video/x-msvideo', 
                                    'video/x-flv' ]


end
```

And this is the error message I get when I try and submit a new attachment:

```
NoMethodError in HelpsController#create

undefined method `validates_attachment' for #<Class:0x00000005581498>
```

If I remove the validates_attachment line everything works, just no file validation.

I have gem 'paperclip' in my gemfile and I'm running in development mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is your project Ruby on Rails 3?  Also, what version of paperclip are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and I think because I don't specify a version for the rails gem in my Gemfile it defaults to the newest version available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [github of paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) the "new style" validator should look like. This applies to paperclip 3.0 and beyond

```
validates :attachment, :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => ['image/png', 'image/jpg']}
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the response. I tried this but I'm getting a new error: `Unknown validator: 'AttachmentContentTypeValidator'` I'll check the link though

Comment: I think that means you're on a older version of paperclip

Comment: Wow, go figure. Just looked at my Gemfile.lock file and it's says paperclip (2.4.5)..... Jeez.... I didn't know you have to manually specify a gem version to get the latest version like that.... this is going to ruin my app if I try and upgrade I just know it haha.

Comment: New error message using this is:  undefined method `image_col_name_content_type' for #<Model>  Why aren't the old methods all backwards compatible?  No one should ever have to modify working code unless doing a major-version upgrade - if then.